# Curses Difference between newwin and subwin

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

i don't seem to be able to find any informations about the difference between curses.newwin and curses.subwin

do you know any?

i'd like to have a screen divided in 3 different sections with different updates times (not everything must be updated every keypress).
 is this the correct direction to go?

thank you

Answer (score 6):

Docu not for Python, but could help you.

> Calling **newwin()** creates and returns a pointer to a new window with
>   the given number of lines and columns. The upper left-hand corner of
>   the window is at line begin_y, column begin_x. If either nlines or
>   ncols is zero, they default to LINES-begin_y and COLS-begin_x. A new
>   full-screen window is created by calling newwin(0,0,0,0).
>
> Calling **subwin()** creates and returns a pointer to a new window with
>   the given number of lines, nlines, and columns, ncols. The window is
>   at position (begin_y, begin_x) on the screen. (This position is
>   relative to the screen, and not to the window orig.) The window is
>   made in the middle of the window orig, so that changes made to one
>   window will affect both windows. The subwindow shares memory with the
>   window orig. When using this routine, it is necessary to call
>   touchwin() or touchline() on orig before calling wrefresh() on the
>   subwindow.

http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/curs_window.3.asp

Comment: thank you, this is really useful information! do you have any idea about the split screen solution ? i mean: is there a better way than another? or either one is ok ?